# Module not specified при запуске сервера tomcat

Tags: tomcat

При запуске tomcat сервера вылезает ошибка Module not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед запуском зайдите в папку где находится `apache tomcat`, найдите файл `start.bat` и запустите его.